# How to change html of div in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a page which displays all **comments (using ng-repeat)**. Each comments are with edit button. Here is my client's requirement.

- On clicking on edit, **comment div should be swapped by form**.
- On submitting form, **form should be swapped by comment div**.
- At a time, only one comment can be updated.

So as per my angularjs knowledge, I can do this with single form for all comments. But I'm getting confuse that how I should do? ng-swap, template directive or something else. And I have also only basic knowledge of angularJS, So if anyone can help me with demo/example, it will be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

**HTML**

```
<div id="comment_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="comment in blog.comments track by $index">
    <div class="replace-with" ng-if="hideComment != $index">
        <h2>
            <b>comment</b> added by <b>{{comment.user.fullname}}</b>, <span><span>{{comment.datetime}}</span></span>
            <div>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="openEditForm($index, comment.unique_id)"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
            </div>
        </h2>
        <p>{{comment.content}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.hideComment = null;
$scope.openEditForm = function (div_id, id)
{
    $scope.hideComment = div_id;

    var html = '<form role="form" name="formUpdateComment" id="formUpdateComment">'
            + '<div class="box-body">'
            + '<div class="form-group">'
            + '<textarea ckeditor="editorOptions" id="taContent" name="taContent" rows="10" cols="80" ng-model="blog.blog_comments[' + div_id + '].content" ng-change="updateContent(' + div_id + ', \'edit\')"></textarea>'
            + '</div>'
            + '</div>'
            + '<div class="box-footer">'
            + '<div style="text-align: right;">'
            + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="closeEditForm(' + div_id + ')">Close</button>'
            + '</div>'
            + '</div>'
            + '</form>';

    $('#comment_' + div_id).append($compile(html)($scope));
}
$scope.closeEditForm = function (div_id)
{
    $('#comment_' + div_id + ' form').remove();
    $scope.hideComment = null;
}
```

In `openEditForm()`, I want to change/swap content of div having id as comment_* with form. On clicking `ok` button, form will be replaced by div content (i.e, `<h2>`,`<p>` etc.). I haven't problem to load updated data etc. My pain is how to change html content. I can't go with this way. Because it will be headache to add more inputs in the form. So I want to use angular directive.

Comment: post what you have tried

Comment: @StarkButtowski, I have updated my question.

Comment: add the corresponding angular code which will give much more clarity on what you actually want

Comment: @StarkButtowski, I haven't do any angular code as I'm confuse that how to do it.

Comment: try changing this `$('#comment_' + div_id).html(html);`

Comment: @HardikVaghani, I have tried that. The code above is working. But my problem is that I want to do this in proper way. Because when there will be too many inputs in the form, it will be headache to handle html string. So I want to do this in AngularWay.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it with `ng-if`.

First, in your controller, define the following variable which will be responsible for showing `ckeditor`:

```
$scope.showCkeditor = false;
```

Then, in your edit function, set it to True:

```
function edit(){
    ...
    $scope.showCkeditor = true;
}
```

Then, in your html, do something like this:

```
<ckeditor ng-if="showCkeditor">  // this is just an assumption as you did not show your own code


</ckeditor>

<commend-div ng-if="!showCkeditor">


</comment-div>
```

and do the same with your buttons

Hope it helps

Comment: I have updated my question so you can exact idea. Bdw thnx for your try. But I can't do in this way. According to your answer, I have to put ckeditor for each comment. But I want to use single ckeditor for each comment edit. There will be not two ckeditor at a time. So I think I can do that.